# How to unit test a ObservableCollection list property in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm new to unit testing, and I'm testing several WPF projects using MS test framework. I have many `ObservableCollection<>` properties in the projects, and I wonder what is the best way to unit test them.

Here is the ViewModel Class to test:

```
public class GplViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<gpl> _gplList;

    public ObservableCollection<gpl> GplList
    {
        get => _gplList;
        set
        {
            _gplList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("GplList");
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class gpl
{
    public string propertyName { get; set; }
    public bool isWin10 { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the latest unit test code after taking the suggestions from comments:

```
public void TestGplList()
{
     List<gpl> listOfCpls = new List<Gpl>();
     gpl Gpl = new gpl();
     listOfGpls.Add(Gpl);

     bool didFire = false;
     GplViewModel _viewModel = new GplViewModel();
     ObservableCollection<gpl> _gplList = new ObservableCollection<gpl>(listOfGpls);

     _viewModel.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
     {
         didFire = true;
         Assert.AreEqual("GplList", e.PropertyName);
         Assert.AreEqual(true, _viewModel.GplList.Equals(_gplList));
     };
     
     _viewModel.GplList = _gplList;
     Assert.IsTrue(didFire);
}
```

Am I testing it right? Is there a better to test it?

Comment: ObservableCollection is part of the framework so it doesn't need to be tested. A better test would be to make sure that viewModel.GplList is the same instance as listOfGpls

Comment: You should ask yourself: "Under what condition would this test fail?". If you can't imagine how it would fail, then it has no value.

Comment: Add/Set an ObservableCollection to GplList and check that PropertyChanged fires your close already.  If you are not the author of the code under test then at least slap him for throwing a property changed event "ConnectionList" when the property is called "GplList".

Comment: Thanks, @JohnV， Here is the test I use to make sure viewModel.GplList is the same instance as listOfGpls.
Assert.AreEqual(true, _viewModel.CplList.SequenceEqual(_cplList));

Comment: That does no test if its the same instance. It tests that the content of the two lists are equal. That also works if both lists are the same instance tho but does not enforce it. A general comment here. You should have some sort of expectation/requirement to test against. If you don't have those what you do isn't a test (IMHO) in the actual sense but more of a thing for regression. You have something that detects behavioral changes that might lead to problems and you now know about those.

Comment: Coming from there you should really test if its the same instance. That is the behavior now and if that changes to getting a copy in the future it sounds like a problem other code might have a using this but your test code does not detect it.

Comment: Thanks, @Ralf, I've used the Assert.AreEqual(true, _viewModel.UserList.Equals(_userList)); tp test if they are the same instance.